# How do I determine the primary IP on a Windows Server 2003 box?

Tags: windows-server-2003, ip-address

How do I determine the primary IP on a Windows Server 2003 box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If the machine has a static IP:**

Click Start

Control Panel

Network Connections

Select the name of your connection (Usually 'Local Are Connection')

Click Properties

From the list of options select 'Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)

Click Properties again

A Properties dialogue will pop up showing IP, Subnet Mask, Gateway and DNS.

Any other IP addresses assigned to the adapter can be found by clicking the 'Advanced' button.

**If the machine has a dynamic (DHCP assigned) address:**

Click start,

Click 'RUN'

In the box that appears type CMD and click 'OK' In the black window that appears on screen type

```
ipconfig /all
```

Hit return

Information about all of your network adapters will be returned including the IP.

Type 'exit' and hit return to end the session

Comment: I find IPCONFIG /ALL to be a lot quicker than opening network settings, anyway; especially on Windows Vista/2008, where network settings are so awfully hidden.

Comment: On Win 2K3 though it just lists all the IP addresses assigned to an adapter, it doesn't tell you which one is the primary.